# Postgres: When to use .end() vs .release() in queries (and does this change in util.promisify)? Does lack of these functions increase memory usage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku, promise

So in my application, I'm using a Postgres DB in a Node.js environment that's deployed to Heroku. I realized that in all of my queries, I don't have a db.release() or db.end(), and I think I need to have those at the end of my functions. I've tried looking around stack and other articles to determine the difference between them, where to use them in the functions, and whether not using them could be causing my Heroku memory capacity to be reached, but I haven't been able to find resources detailing the issues.

First question--When do I use .end() and when do I use .release()? What's the difference, and is there a different function I should use to 'disconnect' from the database?

Second question--in a basic query such as the following, where do I put the .end() or .release()? (AKA before or after the return)

```
db.query(sql, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err.message);
  } else {
    return res;
  }    
})
```

Third question--if I promisify db.query, how do I .end() or .release()?

```
const util = require('util')
const queryP = util.promisify(db.query)
await queryP.call(db, sqlStatement);
```

Final question--could the lack of using .end() or .release() be causing my Heroku memory to be reached, as seen in the linear increasing portion of the memory Metric in the dashboard?

[image: 1]

Just a little note, I require('pg') and run db.connect() early in the Node.js file. Thank you for everything!

Comment: If you use node-postgres, you don't need `util.promisify` - it supports promises natively!

Comment: The first three question should be readily answered by [the docs](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling). If you already read them, please ask specifically about where you feel a clarification is necessary.

Comment: @Bergi Great, I didn't know it natively supported promises, thank you! I read through the documentation, and I guess I don't want to use pool.end() because I'll be connecting users all the time hopefully so the connection should stay open and it would be good to have reusable clients, but could you direct me to a source on how to connect/release clients from the pool properly when making requests? I'm confused because it seems like you run a client.connect() inside a pool query and then run client.release() after but I don't understand how that works...

Comment: You don't use `client.connect()`, you use `pool.connect()` to get a connected client (either reused or new). And then you don't `end` that client connection, but you `release()` that client back to the pool.

Comment: @Bergi I read that you do const client = await pool.connect() at the start of your queries and then you do client.release() as the finally block of a try/catch. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

It is sometimes better to just use pool.query() to query the DB instead of using client.query(), you are not required to deal with releasing clients then.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31954659)